# Aligned allocation with STL vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-alignment

I want my vectors' storage to be aligned (say to a 16 bytes boundary), so I have this allocator as a wrapper to `memalign()`, I am wondering if this is the correct way to allocate aligned memory used with STL vectors.

```
template <class T , int Alignment=16>
class AlignedAllocator
{
public:
...

    pointer allocate (size_type size, const_pointer *hint = 0) {
        return (pointer) memalign(Alignment, size*sizeof (T));
    };

    void deallocate (pointer p, size_type size) {
        free(p);
    };
...
}
```

If not, are there any available implementations for aligned allocators that work with STL containers?

*PS: I am compiling with gcc.*

Comment: why no answers mentioning alignas?  @0xFF this is an instance of an XY problem.  You dont really want an aligned allocator or vector, so much as the types to just always be aligned.

Answer (score 1):

The function memalign(3) is obsolete, try using [posix_memalign(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign) instead. Other than that, assuming the `...` in your code means to contain the rest of the required allocator elements your code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. But you will be having problems porting such code to BSD and Darwin.
It is much more robust to write allocation function by hand.

Just new big enough block and return alligned pointer. Also you will need to write custom deallocation function

Comment: Not gonna work because you can't determine the original address to `delete`.

Comment: +1, but you need to allocate enough extra space to store the returned pointer, as to be able to deallocate it (i.e. the pointer->aligned pointer transformation cannot be reverted mathematically)

Comment: @DeadMG: You just need to store that information. You allocate enough space: `sizeof(T)*size + sizeof(void*) + Alignment-1`, and divide the space in: padding before pointer, pointer and aligned memory, returning a pointer to the last block. On deallocation you move back `sizeof(void*)` and read what the value of the original returned pointer is.

Comment: Right, but he did not describe any need to change the deallocation procedure or induce additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on vector implementation, it may choose to allocate slightly bigger buffer and prepend your data with something that will break alignment.

Comment: Negative, allocation policy should reside completely within the allocator used by the vector. If the vector needs memory for bookkeeping it would have to allocate this *separately* from the contained elements.

Comment: @Giel: That is not entirely true. Vectors usually need no extra memory, but if you consider other containers, like for example `std::list` there is a single allocation for the whole node, which means that even if the allocator yields 16-byte aligned memory you are not guaranteed that the stored value is in a 16-byte boundary.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: ah yes, you're right. I see that the GNU STL implementation uses `allocator::rebind< _List_node<T> >` which has two pointers *preceding* the actual data. So for std::list its alignment will definitely be broken (unless it happens to be sizeof (T*) or sizeof (T*) *2).